# Как в ansible JSON inventory передавать в группу ip для каждого хоста?

Tags: python, ansible

Если в группе несколько адресов, то тогда при одной переменной ansible_host на каждый домен присваивается этот ip

```html
 "group": {
    "hosts": [
      "host1.com ",
      "host2.com "
    ],
    "vars": {
      "ansible_host": "10.0.7.32"
    }
  },
```

Как сделать, чтобы у каждого домена был свой ip?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так [сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565561/how-can-i-specify-a-different-domain-name-in-ansible-inventory).

> [all:vars]
>
> host_domain=part.one.of.very.long.internal.domain.name.com
>
> ansible_host='{{ inventory_hostname }}.{{ host_domain }}'
>
> [web]
>
> server1 anotherserver